# LINK OR JUNCTION between three tables

Tags: database, database-design

In database conception, could I make a join between three tables ? Like this: 
[image]

Edit:
I am asking on design, and not code !

Comment: You kinda have 4 tables here, or am I wrong?

Comment: In a relational database, you can join as many tables as you wish.

Comment: This is called "junction" (or "link") table, not "join". JOIN as a query operator. And yes, you can in theory make it reference as many tables as you wish.

Answer (score 3):

this database design is possible and valid. But it is extremely hard to say yes or no, because every database design heavily depends on the requirements. As I can see from the image, you have done something similar to this:

[image]

The red rectangle represents [FOREIGN KEYS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key). If you look at my image, you will see, that the MainTable table has only 3 fields and those 3 fields are foreign keys. This is possible, but when we design, we usually add other fields (not related to other tables) to the table. For example, lets say that:

- Table1 ==> Car
- Table2 ==> Driver
- Table3 ==> City
- MainTable ==> DriverWhoDrivesACarInACity (ridiculous name but you get the point)

With image in mind, you see that in the MainTable, we are actually storing information about which Driver drove a certain Car in which City (dont pay attention to the real life meaning of this, because it is not relevant at this point). Everything looks good. You start your application and you start inserting data. And then some day it happens, that a certain Driver wants to drive a certain Car in a certain City that he already drove in. That means you will have a duplicate row in the table MainTable. And at this point, you see that there could be some problems with this design. And after some thought, you decide to add another field to your MainTable table: you add "Date and time of usage" so that you know when the car was driven.

So now you have something like this:
[image]

Please note that you dont "need" foreign key relationships, it is just a good practice in order to sustain database integrity!

Answer (score 0):

```
select f1.*,f2.*,f3.* from f1 a
join f2 b on a.1=b.1
join f3 c on a.1=c.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample for SQL server...try accordingly.

```
SELECT p.Name, v.Name
FROM Production.Product p
JOIN Purchasing.ProductVendor pv ON p.ProductID = pv.ProductID
JOIN Purchasing.Vendor v ON pv.BusinessEntityID = v.BusinessEntityID
WHERE ProductSubcategoryID = 15
ORDER BY v.Name;
```